# Set up x64 in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64, winapi

I am trying to learn x64 assembly using Visual Studion 2010.

I was following this video tutorial : [x64 Assembly and C++ Tutorial 1: Getting into x64 ASM from C++](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guru397zg2g&feature=share&list=PL0C5C980A28FEE68D)

As it says, I installed Visual Studio 2010, windows 7 SDK 3.5 (ISO install) and edited the configuration.

But when I compile the code, I get following error :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(49,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml64.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"x64\Debug\asm.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Taasm.asm" exited with code 1.
```

What is this problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: I've got the same error, want to know if you solved it and how?

Comment: No, not yet. Actually I was trying to learn assembly (either x86 or x64). I opted x64 only because I got x64 tutorial. So since it is not working, I left x64 and started with x86 (although using same tutorials, need a little effort though since there are some differences)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the assembler output above that line, or build the .asm file by itself.

You should see warnings generated by the assembler
eg. "somefile.asm(564): warning A6004: procedure argument or local not referenced :"

Deal with those warnings. The "exited with code 1" is not very explanatory.